# How to clear Last_SQL_Error in show slave status

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

a failed "create user root" query error is being displayed in show slave status\G

Password is visible there and I want to clear the error. How should I?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE;
START SLAVE;
```

- read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reset-slave.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use @tombom `RESET SLAVE` at your own risk. In my options you need to make sure your data match with the current position of bin-log slave point to.

> RESET SLAVE makes the slave forget its replication position in the master's binary log
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset-slave.html